# How do I assign an array of books in my book catalog to their respective author?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to keep the authors that are added separately from the other authors that can be added by the jQuery. When I add an author I want to be able to link that Author to his books for example after I press the add author button I get a form for another author but in my code all the authors are in an array and all the books are in another. Not separating from authors and their books.

I want to send via post something like:

```
author1: {book1, book2, book3}
author2: {book4, book5}
author3: {book6, book7, book8, book9}
```

This is the code that I have so far:

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="next.php" method="post">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <div class="input_fields_wrap">
            <button class="add_author">Add Author</button>

            <div id="commonPart" class="commonPart">
                <br>
            <div><input type="text" name="myAuthorText[]" placeholder="Auth name"></div>

            <button class="add_book">Add Author Books</button>
            <div><input type="text" class="bookname" name="myBooksText[]" placeholder="Book name"></div>

             </div>   
        </div>
        <input name="Send" class="submit" value="Send" type="submit">

    </form>
</div> 
<script src="../js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var commonPart      = $("#commonPart"); 
    var add_author      = $(".add_author"); //Add button ID
    var add_subButton   = $(".add_book"); //Add sub button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_author).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            var htmlToAdd = commonPart.clone().attr("id","commonPart_"+x);
            htmlToAdd.find(".addedDiv").remove();
            $(wrapper).append(htmlToAdd); //add input box
          x++; //text box increment
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click",".add_book",function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(this).closest(".commonPart").append('<div class="addedDiv"><input type="text" class="bookname" name="myBooksText[]" placeholder="Book name"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

//http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery
</SCRIPT>
```

**JSFiddle Links:**

[JSFiddle I](http://jsfiddle.net/zzhf7L8a/2/embedded/)

[JSFiddle II (collaboration)](http://jsfiddle.net/zzhf7L8a/#&togetherjs=ChB5gtRUy7)

Answer (score 3):

This is what I found I could have done!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
      <head>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <style type="text/css">
        <!--
        #main {
         max-width: 800px;
         margin: 0 auto;
        }
        -->
       </style>
      </head>
      <body>
       <div id="main">
        <h1>Add or Remove text boxes with jQuery</h1>
         <button onclick="addAuthor()" >Add Author</button><br><br>
         <div id="addAuth"></div>
         <br><br>
         <button onclick="submit()" >Submit</button>
        </div>
        
        <div id="result" ></div>
       </div>
       
       <script type="text/javascript">
        var authors = 0;
                    
        function addAuthor(){
         authors++;
         var str =   '<br/>'
                                    +'<div id="auth'+authors+'"><input type="text" name="author" id="author'+authors+'" placeholder="Author Name:"/>'
            +'<br/>'
                                    +'<button onclick="addMore(\'auth'+authors+'\')" >Add Book</button>'
            +'</div>';
         $("#addAuth").append(str);
        }
        
        var count=0;
        function addMore(id){
         count++;
         var str = '<div id="bookDiv'+count+'">'
           +'<input class="'+id+'" type="text" name="book'+id+'" placeholder="Book Name"/>'
//           +'<span onclick="addMore(\''+id+'\')" style="font-size: 20px; background-color: green; cursor:pointer;">+</span>'
           +'<span onclick="removeDiv(\'bookDiv'+count+'\')" style="font-size: 20px; background-color: red; cursor:pointer; margin-left:1%;">Remove</span>'
//                                +'<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'
           +'</div>';
         $("#"+id).append(str);
        }
        
        function removeDiv(id){
         //var val = confirm("Are you sure ..?");
         //if(val){
          $("#"+id).slideUp(function(){
                                $("#"+id).remove();
                            });
         //}
        }
        
        function submit(){
         var arr = [];
         for(i=1; i<=authors; i++){
          var obj = {};
          obj.name = $("#author"+i).val();
          obj.books = [];
          $(".auth"+i).each(function(){
           var data = $(this).val();
           obj.books.push(data);
          });
          
          arr.push(obj);
         }
         
         $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(arr));
        }
       </script>
      </body>
     </html>
```